# Extract ggplot smoothing function and save in dataframe

Tags: ggplot2, extract, na, smoothing, curve

I am trying to extract my smoothing function from a ggplot and save it as dataframe (hourly datapoints) [Plot shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cfjc.png).

*What I have tried:*

I have already tried different interpolation techniques, but the results are not satisfying.

- Linear interpolation causes a zic-zac pattern.
- Na_spline causes a weird curved pattern.

The real data behaves more closely to the geom_smoothing of ggplot. I have tried to reproduce it with the following functions:

```
loess.data <- stats::loess(Hallwil2018_2019$Avgstemp~as.numeric(Hallwil2018_2019$datetime), span = 0.5)
loess.predict <- predict(loess.data, se = T)
```

- But it creates a list that misses the NA values and is much shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `newdata` argument to `predict()` to get it to predict a value for every time period you give it. For example (from randomly generated data):

```r
df <- data.frame(date = sample(seq(as.Date('2021/01/01'), 
                                   as.Date('2022/01/01'), 
                                   by="day"), 40),
           var = rnorm(40, 100, 10))


mod <- loess(df$var ~ as.numeric(df$date), span = 0.5)

predict(mod, newdata = seq(as.Date('2021/01/01'), as.Date('2022/01/01'), by="day"))
```